# Ubuntu 18.04 server dosn't boot after shrinking image

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning, qemu, disk-image

I converted my physical Ubuntu 18.04 server maschine into an image running on unRaid.

Cause the image is 1TB (size of the original HDD) and the data itself is just about 170GB, i shrinked the main partition vda2 with gparted to 200GB.

At this Point the vm is running fine.
But the image is still 1TB with about 800GB unpartitioned wasted space.

I followed Spaceinvader Ones [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJBrEoq8mHo) to shrink the image down to 250GB via qemus resize command. Just to leave some spare and increacing the partition later to the full 250GB.

But after shrinking the the image to 250GB the vm dosn't boot anymore.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxfkh.jpg

Since two month now i'm stuck here. Tryed several things but nothing workted or broke it even more. (I have backups!)
e.g. this one: [Link](https://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=42844.msg610268#msg610268) [German Mint Forum]

I've 1TB left on the HDD, but it would be great to move it to an fast SSD to increase the performance since the vm is running a gameserver. And 1TB SSDs are not cheap (not for me). And even with the normal HDD it's a waste of storage-space.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The VM is Ubuntu 18.04 Server